# Numpy indexing: first (varying) number of elements from each row in 2d array

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

(short version of my question: In numpy, is there an elegant way of emulating `tf.sequence_mask` from tensorflow?)

I have a 2d array `a` (each row represents a sequence of different length). Next, there is a 1d array `b` (representing sequence lengths). Is there an elegant way to get a (flattened) array that would contain only such elements of `a` that belong to the sequences as specified by their length `b`:

```
a = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3, 2, 1],  # I want just [:3] from this row
    [4, 5, 5, 5, 1],  # [:2] from this row
    [6, 7, 8, 9, 0]   # [:4] from this row
])
b = np.array([3,2,4])  # 3 elements from the 1st row, 2 from the 2nd, 4 from the 4th row
```

the desired result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

By `elegant way` I mean something that avoids loops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to create a mask of the same shape as the 2D array and then simply mask and extract valid elements -

```
a[b[:,None] > np.arange(a.shape[1])]
```

Sample run -

```
In [360]: a
Out[360]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 2, 1],
       [4, 5, 5, 5, 1],
       [6, 7, 8, 9, 0]])

In [361]: b
Out[361]: array([3, 2, 4])

In [362]: a[b[:,None] > np.arange(a.shape[1])]
Out[362]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Comment: This was extremely fast. Thanks! Actually, it was so fast I can't even accept the answer yet...